# How can I run clustalw using Biopython

Tags: biopython

I am using windows 7. I have installed python 2.7 and Biopython 1.57. I created the following script:

```
from Bio.Clustalw import MultipleAlignCL 
cl = MultipleAlignCL("myseqs.fasta") 
print("Command line: %s"%cl) 
clpath="C:\Program Files\ClustalW2\clustalw2.exe" 
cl = MultipleAlignCL("myseqs.fasta",command=clpath) 

from Bio.Clustalw import do_alignment align = do_alignment(cl)
```

But I got an error message.

Comment: According to the http://www.drive5.com/muscle/, Muscle now outperforms clustalw and biopython can work with both.

Answer (score 4):

This is a poorly worded question - where are the details?

Have you been able to install and run ClustalW at the command line by hand? What version? What version of Biopython did you try? Which OS are you using (that can make a big difference)? What error messages did you get?

Have you tried the examples of running ClustalW in the Biopython Tutorial? http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html or http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.pdf

Comment: Than u very much for your comment. I am using windows 7. I have installed python 2.7 and Biopython 1.57. The following script I used to run clustalw. But I got the error message. Please help me.from Bio.Clustalw import MultipleAlignCL
cl = MultipleAlignCL("myseqs.fasta")
print("Command line: %s"%cl)
clpath="C:\Program Files\ClustalW2\clustalw2.exe"
cl = MultipleAlignCL("myseqs.fasta",command=clpath)
from Bio.Clustalw import do_alignment
align = do_alignment(cl)

Comment: What error? Also don't use Bio.Clustalw as it has been deprecated.